# Is there a samba setting that restricts the number of client connections?

Tags: samba

Im trying to setup two ip cameras to use the same samba share and same credentials. Intermittently they both work properly but most of the time only one of them will work(i think it is the first one to connect) In the scenario where one is working and one is not, the logs of the of the non working cam will say "storage is not writeable" and the samba logs dont show anything relevant. Samba server is running on a raspberry pi 3b+ running raspian stretch. My samba config is stock aside from the share settings and the share path is 777.